# How to stream data that is generated by an IoT gateway application to predix cloud?

Tags: iot, predix

I've devices configured with IoT gateway application(built with MEAN.JS), these devices send data to IoT gateway where i can access data now i wish to do some analytics on same data how can i send this data to [predix cloud](https://www.predix.io/) so that i can use predix services for analytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve this requirement using [predix-uaa-client](https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-uaa-client) NPM package
all you've to do is-

1.create a predix account, predix-uaa service, predix-time-series service and attach uaa-service & time-series service

2.Make note of Uaa Url, client_id, client_secret and predix time-series ingest zone id

pass Uaa Url, client_id, client_secret and predix time-series ingest zone id to predix-uaa-client package it responses with token.access_token.
Use token.access_token as a Bearer token Authroization header in calls to secured services.
once it securely calls service create websocket connection and start sending data to predix-time-series service

[here](https://gist.github.com/srinivasyl/8f85933a6ad86f6114c14b1267c4d129) sample code to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

First you need to sign up for a free Predix account on predix.io.  Subscribe to the (free version) of the UAA service, and Time Series database service.  Create a UAA Client with permissions to access your Time Series instance.  Then you can use a websocket to securely push data into the cloud.  You can learn more by using the Predix Toolkit:  https://predix-toolkit.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/
(Source code for the toolkit is here: https://github.com/predixdev/security-starter)

Lots of helpful tutorials are here:
https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials

Comment: thanku your answer was usefull for me. by the way is it mandatory to configure predix machine on edge device to push data to predix cloud if so which tutorial should i follow for my requirement

Comment: As you told i created uaa client and time series instance i tried websocket to push data to cloud  but it always throws this  `{
  "error": "Error: unexpected server response (401)",
  "url": "wss://gateway-predix-data-services.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/v1/stream/messages"
}`